# Wrong encoding of "file name from a file handle"

Tags: winapi, unicode

I have used this code in msdn ([Obtaining a file name from a file handle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366789%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) to obtain the file name of a file handle that i got from [findfirstchangenotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365261%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

But now the problem is that the encoding of the resulting string is somehow wrong. I just see one character instead of all characters (usually a question mark).

So my code calls `GetMappedFileName`, and gets question marks.

```
 if (GetMappedFileName (GetCurrentProcess(), 
                         pMem, 
                         pszFilename,
                         MAX_PATH))
```

Why?

Comment: Seeing only a single character is a sure sign of casting a wchar_t* string to a char* string.  Those kind of casts only lets you shut up the compiler trying to tell you that you are doing it wrong.  Don't cast, use Unicode consistently.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling the 'A' form of `GetMappedFileName`, which can only deliver characters in your current ACP. Your filename has characters not in the current ACP, so they get turned to question marks.

If the file name includes Unicode characters that have no representation in your current ACP, you will get question marks. You should call the 'W' form of the API to get the Unicode form of the file name, and then decide what you want to do with it.